# Outlook style br tag height from CSS only

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Is there a way to style 
 to give it height within outlook?

The original HTML provided is locked in a template, however, css can still be modified.

The following code is respected in several clients, but unsurprisingly not in outlook on windows:

```
br{
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Really in email docs .. You should be using tables instead of `div`s and `br` tags --   The CSS for `div` and `br` support is going to be extremely limited in various email clients.

Comment: The html body being generated is fixed, I have no means of changing it.

Comment: Well then, given your restrictions  .. The answer is no, you cannot adjust a br tag to suit email clients like Outlook with CSS.  Whoever designed the templates *should* be quite aware that basically `<table>` tags are the only "sure-fire" design tactic when it comes to email templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Zak has mentioned, use `td` to add height to different sections of my email.

```
<tr>
    <td height="30" style="height:30px; line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">&zwnj;</td>
</tr>
```

This will ensure the height of a table cell is the same on all different devices.
`zwnj` is used because if you have an email editor, at times it adds `nbsp` for empty cells. So if you have `zwnj` it will not add anything and spacing will always be right.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook rendering engine looks to change a `<br>` into `<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN>&nbsp;</span></p>`

Targeting that doesn't work either, as in for example:

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
   p.MsoNormal {
        height:200px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Outlook either changes the output (e.g. background to transparent), or disregards it (e.g. height).

So you can't do anything from just the CSS.

Comment: Just curious, is that before or after forwarding? In my experience I have only seen Outlook display HTML as is. It does not change HTML unless its setup to do so from the receiving server.

Comment: Outlook (desktop, Windows) has always drastically changed the HTML... that's why it's so difficult to render on

Comment: only time i see `<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN>&nbsp;</span></p>` is when forwarded. My emails have never failed me yet.

Comment: @Syfer I thnk you might be confusing the 'View Source' which allows you to see unchanged code, and the actual processed HTML. I'm not sure if you can pull it easily out, but using Litmus it's fairly easy. See https://litmus.com/blog/new-in-litmus-processed-html-support